# MediaWiki and EU cookie consent

Tags: google-adsense, legal, mediawiki, cookie, eu-cookie-law

I own a MediaWiki website that is showing Google AdSense. As of September 30th 2015 AdSense requires compliance with the [EU cookie law](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14472/why-is-the-eu-cookie-directive-causing-so-much-excitement/14495#14495).

The Google Adsense Team is pointing to https://www.google.com/about/company/user-consent-policy-help.html and it looks as if Adsense will be disabled on websites that don't follow this page and https://www.cookiechoices.org/.

There are some okay solutions [for Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/eu_cookie_compliance) and 
[for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/eu-cookie-law), but I haven't yet found anything obvious for MediaWiki. What's the best way to move forward with this?

I'm open to creating a MediaWiki extension, but I'm not sure what would be a good starting point. Maybe [cookieguard](http://cookieguard.eu/), a jQuery plugin? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this not what you are looking for? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CookiePolicy?

Answer (score 1):

EU Cookie law was finally recognised as mostly unimplementable nonsense and backtracked a bit and so the info in your linked question is largely out of date. EU directives are not law themselves but instantiated by laws in the member states so your actual requirement depends on the specific country you do business/host in.

Generally you don't actually need an annoying pop-up if you are only using the standard cookies, just a visible link to a cookie policy page listing what ones are used. So as a static page this won't require a plugin.

Comment: I don't care much what the EU thinks (most official EU websites are not even compliant with their own silly policy), but I care a lot about what the Google Adsense Team thinks and that they might stop serving ads or even close my account. I added two relevant links Google points to. I don't think a static page will cut it.

Comment: @KasperSouren well you do care because adsense is requiring you to comply. This is about the UK in particular but other countries have taken a laxer approach and others have ignored the directive completely! http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2012/may/26/cookies-law-changed-implied-consent

EU directives are for countries to follow in setting law, they do not apply to individuals or companies. You have to comply with the most restrictive individual EU country's law to be compliant.

Answer (score 0):

[Cookie Guard](http://cookieguard.eu/) lets you list all the known cookies used on your site and offers site visitors the opportunity to block or allow non-essential and unknown cookies.

It's the best starting point for MediaWiki website as this EU law concerned.

Comment: Was this anyway helpful? :)