# Cookie consent messages required on websites - how will adsense work?

Tags: javascript, google-adsense, legal, cookie, google-adsense-policies

I ended up watching this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5xVSXTn41Y

It states that publishers have until September 30th, 2015 to add a visible message indicating about the use of cookies on their websites.

The problem here is that I have Adsense on my website, and google automatically adds cookies when it displays ads.

If the European Union wants users to choose whether to accept or reject the use of cookies and the user chooses to reject, then how will Adsense function properly?

Why can't Google add Javascript functionality that one can apply to their website to allow ads to show without cookies?

Comment: I think that the EU cookie (I prefer a good brownie myself preferably without nuts unless that cookie is chocolate chip or another favorite- then I might have to think about it...) requirement are for sites that originate in the EU and serve the EU. But this is a damned good question regardless. Seems like there is a paradox here.

Comment: well I want my website to serve the world. I have pages indexed on google, bing, yandex and possibly baidu.

Comment: It should still work the same... it is just a EU law (if I remember right) that sites originating in the EU and serving the EU must have this here cookie thingie to protect peoples privacy. I personally feel it is damned silly, especially in light of how easy it is to delete cookies and read a privacy policy... that that is neither here nor there. Okay- it is there... in the EU...

Comment: @closetnoc It's supposed to be for any sites serving content in the EU, regardless of where they are hosted. (Yes, it is "damned silly".)

Comment: @w3d Ooopppsss! Effum!! Ain't be happenin on my sites. What are they gunna do? Slap me into silly court?

Comment: Related but different question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/84847/24487

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those tricky ones, not just from a legal standpoint but also from a technical standpoint. The legal issues are a bit beyond the scope of Webmasters SE and would really depend on legal advice obtained for your specific situation but mainly as I see it would be if technically you are bound by EU law if your site is not hosted in the EU and not specifically targeted to the EU.

From the technical standpoint due to browser security and cross domain issues there would be no way for you to do anything to affect the AdSense cookie (such as deleting it). I have used two different options in the past both of which where assessed by a clients legal rep's as being compliant...

### Option 1 - Don't Show AdSense Without Consent

In this impllementation we showed the cookie consent message at the top of the page and when the user clicked ok the AdSense code was added to the page and the ads where shown.

### Option 2 - Inform of AdSense Cookie Use and Link Away On Non Agreement

In this instance AdSense was required for the the site so the user was presented with a cookie consent page before being able to do anything in the site. Once the user agreed to the cookies, including the AdSense cookie the user was taken to the site, if they didn't agree to the cookies they where redirected to a different page saying that the site could not be used without cookies.

Either way you need to make an assessment on what solution meets your needs. Google has released a site which is at https://www.cookiechoices.org/ and provides information to site publishers on complying with EU cookie laws including third party solutions that can be used to enable cookie management for sites in line with EU requirements.